# How to ssh into a remote server, run commands and stay on the server

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

For example I wish ssh into a remote server and run a series of commands like (just some random commands)

```
touch foo.txt
echo 'bar' > foo.txt
cd ..
ls
```

and stay in that connection?

I know about `ssh $myserver <commands>` that runs the commands but I couldn't find ways to stay in that connection.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
 ssh -t linuxuser@host "commands; bash"
```

`-t` forces the host to allocate a virtual terminal to the process, which allows it to stay open.

Comment: Awesome! it worked! but somehow it landed my in a different directory than if I ssh normally. any explanations on that?